# Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 on if/else statement

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have an issue and I don't understand on how to fix it.
I try to take the gender of the uid based on 2 collection, if is male in the UI have to show a certain widget, if is women another one, but I take the error on the title, if uid is a man I take the error on the 'women' var, if uid is a women I have the problem in the 'man' var.
I don't know how to fix it, please help!

```
genere() async {

   QuerySnapshot querySnap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('contatore').where('Sesso', isEqualTo: 'Uomo').where('uid', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).get();
   var man = querySnap.docs[0]['Sesso'] == 'Uomo';
   var prenotato = querySnap.docs[0]['Prenotato'] == true;

//Donna
   var querySnapD = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('contatoreD').where('Sesso', isEqualTo: 'Donna').where('uid', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).get();
   var women = querySnapD.docs[0]['Sesso'] == 'Donna';
   var prenotatoD = querySnapD.docs[0]['Prenotato'] == true;

   if(man && prenotato) {
     setState(() {
     isUomo = true;
     isPren = true;
   });
   }
   if(women && prenotatoD) {
       setState(() {
         isDonna = true;
         isPrenD = true;
       });
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **DocumentSnapshot** instead of **QuerySnapshot**, which is more efficient to get user info using UID:

```
Future<void> genere() async {
  var currentUserUid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

  DocumentSnapshot maleDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('male')
      .doc(currentUserUid)
      .get();

  if (maleDoc.exists) {
    var prenotato = maleDoc.get('Prenotato') == true;

    setState(() {
      isUomo = true; //setting to true as it fetched from male collection
      isPren = prenotato;
    });
  } else {
    DocumentSnapshot femaleDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('female')
        .doc(currentUserUid)
        .get();

    if (femaleDoc.exists) {
      var prenotato = femaleDoc.get('Prenotato') == true;

      setState(() {
        isUomo = false; //setting to false as it fetched from female collection
        isPren = prenotato;
      });
    } else {
      throw "No Data Found";
    }
  }
}
```

and Use one variable for gender information and use it like this :

```
isPren ? (isUomo ? MaleWidget() : FemaleWidget()) : NotBookedWidget()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks man, the problem is that I have male and female on 2 different collection, one is contatore and second is contatoreD

Comment: Updated the answer but for future projects keep the users data in one collection or better, if this project is not yet released then use one collection.

Comment: Give me this error on femaleDoc.get('Prenotato')
Unhandled Exception: Bad state: cannot get field "Prenotato" on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist

Comment: move prenotato variable inside if(femaleDoc.exists) same like maleDoc

Comment: Man sorry, don't hate me.
I need also other field to match with this 2, and this field is on other collections calls users ( I know is a caos) btw is a boolean value, if it true need to show male or female widget but when is false a text like 'No booking made, make it and be the first' how can I take that and put inside the code that u write before? 

Sorry for the trouble and thanks a lot, unfortunally I'm completely new on flutter and also in programming and also if I try I can't reach the goal :(

Comment: For no booking I have updated the answer. And I would suggest u to learn to structure your data. If you need another 2 calls to get other fields then It is surely is a mess. As this scales up it'll be hard to keep track.

Comment: Thanks man, as soon as possibile I try the code. 
Yes, you’re right and I know it, for this reason when I release this first version I work to clean all the code, data and so on to make it better 